# Site slowdown and errors after switching from .NET 2 to .NET 4

Tags: .net, sql-server, nhibernate

We changed the .NET version on a legacy web app from 2 to 4.

1. The app became significantly slower and
2. We now get this error in some cases:

   `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 85) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.`

That error is thrown on a `SELECT` query while running a search/lookup type operation. (Not an update type operation).

The legacy app is running NHibernate version 2.2 which is fairly old. That package generating a lot of queries. Just upgrading to the latest version 3.2 did not improve speed. It does seem to get rid of the error. But it causes other bugs so we can't just upgrade without major analysis & testing.

Finally my questions:

1. Any suggestions?
2. We added `WITH (NOLOCK)` to the SQL query and the error went away. But could this cause other problems? (Given that no updates are done during the user actions that cause this error - I'm not sure why Transactions are involved in searching).

We are very new to this app, having taken over from another developer. So any help is appreciated, even just how to go about debugging. We are trying many things but are not very familiar with NHibernate, so specifically any insights on NHibernate and the .NET version would be great.

Comment: David, I've run some queries from stackoverflow to look at indexes but don't see anything enlightening. What should I be looking for? Thanks.

Comment: I should add a couple of things. First, the database is on a separate server which was not upgraded in any way. Second, we did add one field to one table (a string field to store some user preferences). That table only had an index on its ID field.

Comment: Well first of all you should verify that there *are* indexes. Second, you should make sure that they're in the right places, which is an art form in itself, but basically comes down to: try to think of queries that are being executed a lot, and at which fields they're being accessed (mainly, which fields are used for finding records, in the `where` clauses of your queries?, and make sure that *they* are indexed. Foreign keys are often a good place to start. But fortunately you don't have to guess, you can use SQL Server Profiler to find out which queries are being executed frequently, or have

Comment: very high duration. Note that these recommendations have no bearing at all on why the framework upgrade should have started the problems. These are general SQL Server performance hints. A SQL deadlock still is a sure sign of SQL Server resource contention. Surely, the application may be the right place to start looking for a solution, if, for instance, you're suddenly executing unreasonably many queries. SQL Server Profiler should be able to tell you that as well.

Comment: OK, got it. As the server performance went from excellent to slow literally at the turn of the .NET switch, we didn't think to do a more general analysis of query performance. But I see what you mean and yes, we'll use the profiler. In fact there's a web.config setting to turn on sql query logging and timing - works nicely in dev but I'm scared to turn that on in production without knowing if it would overwhelm the system. Maybe after-hours. Thanks for the suggestions! Sorry I don't have enough mojo yet here to upvote you. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is that the upgrade has introduced an error and you are not gracefully issuing a `rollback`.  As weird as this sounds upgrading from .net2 to .net4 could have introduced  a NH session problem. This might also be the case if you have gone from classic to integrated modes.

One option to discount my theory is to download [NHProf](http://nhprof.com/) and run your tests locally (including stress tests) to see if you are getting sessions that are not opening/closing/commiting properly.

Even if it is not a session problem NHProf might show you the places where your problematic queries are. Whilst testing I would also fire up `SQL Server Profiler` to discount David's theory.

I think these two options are your best bet.

Comment: I believe we also switched from classic to integrated. I will try your suggestions. Thank you very much, will report back here at some point.

Comment: In the end, it turned out to be some tiny coding change we had made in the process of taking over this project. Our developer had flipped a switch in dev mode to test something and then forgot to turn it off. It got promoted to live. Using NHProf greatly helped us figuring out what was going on - as you said - and once we knew that it was simple to look at the SVN diffs and figure out what we did. Huge thanks to you, and to David too for the helpful hints on SQL profiling.

Comment: Done. Didn't know I could do that now (I must have leveled up!). Thanks again!